# How to send an AJAX request from node-express?

Tags: ajax, node.js

in a node-express server, i'm getting a huge array of IP address, i want to visualize it on a map in the client.

Due to the data set is huge, i think it's better to return the client a json containing an array of longitude and latitude.

The thing is, from IP address to geo location, i need to send a ajax request to an api. Can i do this in the server?

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://api/'+ip,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (res) {
         //do something;
        }
   });
```

Thanks.

Comment: i see no `host` in url param.

Comment: @Ravi, i don't want to advertise for the api so fake it...

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, you'd have something like :

```
app.get('/api/:ip',function(req, res){
    var ip = req.params.ip;
    geolocalizeIp(ip,function(latlng){ //you have to write this function
      res.json(latlng);
    });
});
```

And the client would get it using :

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://yourserver/api/'+ip,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (res) {
         //res is yourArray, do stuff with it here;
        }
   });
```